# Classify a text with weka after classifier has been trained

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am a beginner with weka.

I have managed to import dataset from the disk (one folder by category, all text related to this category inside the folder), apply StringToWordVector with tokenizer, train a Naive Multniomial categorizer ... The code is below (it is c# but Java is ok of course)

However, I can hardly find information on how to use the categorizer on a project. Say I have a text with unknown category, input by a user, how can I just apply the categorizer to this text and infer the category it belongs to ? (code "// what to do here below"). 
Any help would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Thanks in advance

Julien

```
string filepath = @"C:\Users\Julien\Desktop\Meal\";
    ClassificationDatasetHelper classHelper = new ClassificationDatasetHelper();
    weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader tdl = new
    weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader();
    tdl.setDirectory(new java.io.File(filepath));
    tdl.setCharSet("UTF-8");

    weka.core.Instances insts = tdl.getDataSet();

    weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector swv = new weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector();
    swv.setInputFormat(insts);
    swv.setDoNotOperateOnPerClassBasis(false);
    swv.setOutputWordCounts(true);
    swv.setWordsToKeep(1000);
    swv.setIDFTransform(true);
    swv.setMinTermFreq(1);
    swv.setDoNotOperateOnPerClassBasis(false);
    swv.setPeriodicPruning(-1);
    weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer tokenizer = new weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setNGramMinSize(2);
    tokenizer.setNGramMaxSize(2);
    swv.setTokenizer(tokenizer);

    insts = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(insts, swv);

    insts.setClassIndex(0);

    weka.classifiers.Classifier cl = new weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomial();
    int trainSize = insts.numInstances() * percentSplit / 100;
    int testSize = insts.numInstances() - trainSize;
    weka.core.Instances train = new weka.core.Instances(insts, 0, trainSize);

    cl.buildClassifier(train);
    string s = "Try to classify this text";
    weka.core.Instance instanceToClassify = new weka.core.Instance();

    // what to do here
    // ???

    double predictedClass = cl.classifyInstance(instanceToClassify);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best place to learn how to use Weka in your Java app is in the official Weka wiki.

https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/use_weka_in_your_java_code/

Basically, you provide a new dataset (the classifier will ignore the category attribute) and you ask it to label each instance for you, like this

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import weka.core.Instances;
 ...
 // load unlabeled data
 Instances unlabeled = new Instances(
                         new BufferedReader(
                           new FileReader("/some/where/unlabeled.arff")));

 // set class attribute
 unlabeled.setClassIndex(unlabeled.numAttributes() - 1);

 // create copy
 Instances labeled = new Instances(unlabeled);

 // label instances
 for (int i = 0; i < unlabeled.numInstances(); i++) {
   double clsLabel = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
   labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);
 }
 // save labeled data
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                           new FileWriter("/some/where/labeled.arff"));
 writer.write(labeled.toString());
 writer.newLine();
 writer.flush();
 writer.close();
```